# what's wrong with my MIPS code? (sum, max, min)

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to print max, min and sum of the digit list. However, Qtspim throws exception error and bad address error. I tried to find the problems for hours, but I couldn't find them. Please help me. 
digit = $s0, length = $s1, sum = $s2, max = $s3, min = $s4, i = $s5

```
.data
digit:   .word 10, 12, 23, 28, 7, 39, 10, 11, 23, 12, 3, 4, 5, 1 
length:   .word 14 # the length of the digit list

.text
main:
    la $s0, digit           #s0 = digit
    la $s1, length          #s1 = length
    add $s2, $zero, $zero   #sum = 0
    lw $t0, 0($s0)          #t0 = digit[0]
    add $s3, $zero, $t0     #max = digit[0]
    add $s4, $zero, $t0     #min = digit[0]
    add $s5, $zero, $zero   #i = 0
Loop:
    beq $s1, $s5, Exit      #branch to Exit if(i==length)
    sll $t0, $s5, 2         #t0 = i*4
    add $t0, $t0, $s0       #t0 = digit + i*4
    lw $t1, 0($t0)          #t1 = digit[i]
    addi $s5, $s5, 1        #i++
    add $s2, $s2, $t1       #sum += digit[i]
    slt $t2, $s3, $t1       #t2 = 1 if(max < digit[i])
    beq $t2, $zero, Min     #if not, go to min
    add $s3, $zero, $t1
Min:
    slt $t2, $t1, $s4       #t2 = 1 if(min > digit[i])
    beq $t2, $zero, Loop
    add $s4, $zero, $t1
    j Loop
Exit:
    ori $v0, $0, 1
    # $a0 = sum
    add $a0, $s2, $zero
    syscall

    ori $v0, $0, 1
    # $a0 = max
    add $a0, $s3, $zero
    syscall

    ori $v0, $0, 1
    # $a0 = min
    add $a0, $s4, $zero
    syscall
.end
```

and this is C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int digit[14] = {10, 12, 23, 28, 7, 39, 10, 11, 23, 12, 3, 4, 5, 1}; //digit = $s0
    int length = 14; //length = $s1
    int sum=0, max, min, i=0; //sum = $s2, max = $s3, min = $s4, i = $s5
    max=min=digit[0];

    while(i != length) 
    {
        if(max < digit[i])
            max = digit[i];
        if(min > digit[i])
            min = digit[i];
        sum += digit[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d", sum, max, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The QtSpim should mark instruction where the problem happened, and you should be able to examine register and memory content at the moment of crash.

Comment: @Ped7g  lw $t1, 0($t0)          #t1 = digit[i] //this part in Loop. and I don't understand why it is wrong

Comment: So now check value in `t0` upon crash, and compare it with  `digit` symbol (which is technically memory address value, which is 32 bit integer). If it is way far away from the original `digit`, then you have wrong pointer. But re-reading that comment (good one actually), I have much bigger suspicion you have address within bounds, but you are working with single-byte (char/digit) element sizes, adjusting address by +1/-1, thus `lw` "load word" will try to access unaligned address = crash. You need `lb` "load byte" in such case. (that will sign-extend 8 bit value into 32bit register).

Comment: `word` memory access on MIPS is possible only with aligned addresses (address is divisible by 4 ⇔ bottom two bits are zero ⇔ you adjust already aligned address only by +-4 multiples).

Comment: And now I was actually not lazy to read your code, and you have `digit:   .word`, so nope, the `lw` is correct way to use those values. You need to fix the address itself, check how `t0` value relates to `digit` symbol. You have either completely wrong memory address, or maybe you by accident advance address by +-1 instead of +-4, but `word` data occupy 4 bytes, so to advance from one element to next you need to do +4. (The C language does use type of pointer to hide the pointer math away from programmer, doing +-4 internally on int* +-1)

Comment: And finally I read your source even more, and just do few steps in debugger into your code, and check also how the "length" ended in `s1`. Your index/pointer math looks to be correct. I guess the length test is wrong, and that makes you run out of valid memory range. And you could have saved all this delay with SO just by doing those few steps in debugger yourself.